# Inner Joining with two tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

I need a little help setting up my query.  I'm simply trying to access the amount of people who are in the same 'clan' by joining these two tables together, clan, users.  Each users has a column 'clan' which is the same as the table clan's column 'roomOwner' and then I'm trying to get the table clan's information along with the amount of members so it would be like: room, roomOwner, members
So basically all I have is this:

```
SELECT c.*, count(u.clan) AS members FROM clans c inner join users u WHERE c.roomOwner = u.clan ORDER BY members;
```

It only shows one clan though. Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has no `GROUP BY` clause. and I think it's only returning single record right? `LEFT JOIN` is needed here since there are possibilities that a `clan` has no member.

```
SELECT  b.roomOwner, COUNT(a.clan) memberCount
FROM    clan b
        LEFT JOIN users a
            ON a.clan = b.roomOwner
GROUP BY b.roomOwner
ORDER BY memberCount
```

Comment: Thanks my final query was:
  `SELECT b. * , COUNT( a.clan ) totalCount, SUM( c.xp ) totalXp
FROM clans b
LEFT JOIN users a ON a.clan = b.roomOwner
LEFT JOIN skillsoverall c ON a.username LIKE c.playerName
GROUP BY b.roomOwner
ORDER BY  `totalXp` DESC 
LIMIT 15`

Comment: Okay that's my query but I'm trying to put a rank number for each one for $i but all I do is have 15 results for every result:

        ``function clans(){
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT b. * , COUNT( a.clan ) totalCount, SUM( c.xp ) totalXp
FROM clans b
LEFT JOIN users a ON a.clan = b.roomOwner
LEFT JOIN skillsoverall c ON a.username LIKE c.playerName
GROUP BY b.roomOwner
ORDER BY  `totalXp` DESC 
LIMIT 15") or die(mysql_error());
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  for($i = 1; $i <=$rows; $i++){;
   echo $i;
  }
 }
}`  I removed some code so it would fit in this comment.

Comment: @BrandonTylerJones it is better to create another question for this :D so many users can view and help you including me :D

Comment: Could you help me with this real quick?  I just need it to print out a number for each row there is kind of like it's a rank.  If I use a for statement it will just print out every row 15 times.

Comment: you can remove the for loop. tyr this, `$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{ 
  echo $i . " " . $row['roomOwner']; 
  $i = $i + 1;
}`

Comment: since you have specified `LIMIT 15`, you don't have to add `for loop`, create a variable outside while and increment it every after echo.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot GROUP BY. Do you have some "id" column in "clans" table? Group by that "id"

```
SELECT c.*, count(u.clan) AS members 
FROM clans c 
inner join users u ON c.roomOwner = u.clan
GROUP BY clans.id
```

And you need LEFT JOIN there instead of INNER JOIN if you want to see info about all clans, even having 0 users.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help:
        select c.*, count(links.id) as members
        from clans c
        left join users u on c.roomOwner = u,clan
        group by u.clan
        order by members